# How to pass a string into MVC model with AutoMapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I'm trying to include a csv string `involvedBody` in a View that is generated using AutoMapper but I can't work out where to map the string to the model.

I assumed it would be in the CreateMap call in the controller or as a `.ForMember` function in the mapping but I can't get it to work. I need to call the `InvolvedBodies` function and pass the string into the model before the model becomes an IOrderedEnumerable.

Is this possible or do I need to try something else?

### ViewModel

```
public partial class FamilyInterventionListViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int interventionId { get; set; }
        public string interventionCategory { get; set; }
        public string interventionType { get; set; }
        public string outcome { get; set; }
        public string achievement { get; set; }
        public string involvedBody { get; set; }
        public string startDate { get; set; }
        public string endDate { get; set; }
        public string notes { get; set; }  
    }
```

### Repository

```
 public string InvolvedBodies(int interventionId)
    {
        var q = (from body in context.tEntity
                 where body.tIntervention.Any(b => b.interventionID == interventionId)
                 select body.entityName
                 );

        var ibcsv = string.Join(",", q.ToArray());                       

        return ibcsv;                    
    }
```

### Controller

```
    public ActionResult InterventionType(int Id, string achievement)
    {
        var model = GetDisplay(Id)
            .Where(m => m.achievement == achievement)
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.startDate)                
            ;           

        return PartialView("_interventionType", model);
    }


//Automapper for display model
private IEnumerable<FamilyInterventionListViewModel> GetDisplay(int Id)
{
    var list = _repo.Get(Id);
    Mapper.CreateMap<tIntervention, FamilyInterventionListViewModel>();
    IEnumerable<FamilyInterventionListViewModel> viewModel = Mapper.Map <IEnumerable<tIntervention>, IEnumerable<FamilyInterventionListViewModel>>(list);            
    return viewModel;
}
```

### Mapping

```
Mapper.CreateMap<tIntervention, FamilyInterventionListViewModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.interventionID))
    .ForMember(d => d.interventionCategory, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.tOutcome.tInterventionCategory.InterventionCategory))
    .ForMember(d => d.interventionType, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.tInterventionType.interventionType))
    .ForMember(d => d.outcome, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.tOutcome.outcome))
    .ForMember(d => d.achievement, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.tAchievement.achievement))
    .ForMember(d => d.involvedBody, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.tEntity.Select(m => m.entityName)))
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not been able to find a solution to this using Automapper so have reverted to manually mapping the csv string after the model is created using:

```
foreach (var item in model)
{
    item.involvedBody = _repo.InvolvedBodies(item.interventionId);
}
```

I'd be interested to know if this is deemed to be good practice or if there is some other technique I should be using.